# How can I get the number of all records in table from a SQLLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get the number of records from my table but I can't because I get this error:

> 06-19 19:11:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(1811): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT  * FROM zapisy)

My function:

```
// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ZAPISY;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

I found this function on this site: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

What's wrong? Why it's not working?

Answer (score 3):

you called `cursor.close()` when you are still using the cursor in the return statement, you cannot close a cursor if you are still using it.

its like closing a door then trying to walk through it :)

Answer (score 1):

you close cursor and then uses it, you need to record the data in another place and return that